# json.loads with a unicode string

Tags: python, json, unicode

I've got a large json formatted string that I'm trying to convert into a python dictionary, but all of the keys and values are in unicode so they have a leading `u` in the string.  When attempting to use `json.loads()` it complains that `ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)` because of the `u`.

I have:

```
x = "{u'abc': [{u'xyz': u'XYZ'}, {u'lmno': u'LMNO'}], u'def': u'DEF'}"
json.loads(x)  --> ValueError
```

I want:

```
x = "{u'abc': [{u'xyz': u'XYZ'}, {u'lmno': u'LMNO'}], u'def': u'DEF'}"
z = x.strip_unicode()
r = json.loads(z)
# r = {'abc': [{'xyz':'XYZ'}, {'lmno': 'LMNO'}], 'def': 'DEF'}
```

So is there something like `strip_unicode` or maybe a different function from json where it can handle the leading `u`?

Comment: JSON doesn't have a concept of a `u` in front of the strings. The string you have is not valid JSON. Is it actually a Python dictionary? You can probably use the `ast` module to load it if so.

Comment: That isn't JSON. Besides the `u` prefix, there's also the fact that JSON doesn't allow single quotes on strings. Someone called `repr` or `str` (or just `print`) on a Python `dict`, and then tried to pass it off to you as JSON.

Comment: `eval(x)` works here

Comment: If that someone is you, fix the code that writes/stores the data. If that someone is a person you work with or have a contract with or have leverage over, make them fix that code. If you really, really can't fix the code that generates this stuff, then you can't parse it with `json.loads`, because it's not JSON. And, because `repr` is not a format designed to be parsed, there _is_ no function that can parse it. For _some_ cases, `ast.literal_eval` will work, but you don't want to rely on that unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @bphi Yes, `eval("{u'abc': __import__('os').system('rm -rf /')}")` does a great job executing arbitrary code.

Comment: @abarnert This case seems to work fine with `ast.literal_eval` though?

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Sure, if all you have is this one example, `ast.literal_eval` works. But if all you have is this one example, `x = {u'abc': [{u'xyz': u'XYZ'}, {u'lmno': u'LMNO'}], u'def': u'DEF'}` works even better—don't make a string, don't parse it, just use a dict display. Presumably, this is just an example, not the OP's entire potential dataset.

Comment: @solarc @abarnert you're right that it's not actually a json string.  I'm trying to test a function that handles json from a request but the (already existing) function that gives me a python dictionary to match the json comes back with the `u` and I'm trying to convert that into a string that the parser can then handle

Comment: SirDeimos: If the existing function already gives you a python dictionary, what turned it into a string with the `u`s in it? What or what turned it into the string that's in `x` that you're now trying to parse with `loads()`?

Comment: @martineau The python dictionary is created with `u`s already in there, when stringifying it, the `u`s are included as part of the string.  The function I'm testing does a `json.loads()` on it so so I'm trying to strip the `u`s before it gets to the function to be tested.

Comment: SirDeimos: The dictionary doesn't have `u`s in it. It has keys and values that are Unicode strings (and you must be using Python 2). The `u`s appear when you turn the dictionary into a string and however you're doing that is using the `repr()` of those values, not the `str()` of them. cont....

Comment: ... You could convert the keys and values to strings (without `u`s) by iteration through all of keys and values returned by `x.items()` and converting each pair to their `str` value. If you want the output to be parsable by `loads()`, you also need to add enclose them in double quotes separated by `:` characters, add commas between them and enclose the whole thing in `{` and `}` brackets so it's the format `json.loads()` wants.

Comment: Ended up just refactoring the function so I could test my added code without needing to do `json.loads()`